# Oracle:  out of process memory when trying to allocate...

Tags: oracle

Привет, знатаком Admin Oracle! С Новым Годом!

Oracle version 9.2.0.8.

> ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 258072 bytes (hash-join subh,kllcqas:kllsltba)

Как быть?!

Еще OS IBM AIX 6.1 Oracle 10gR2 RAC начал выдавать

> ORA-04031: Unable to Allocate xxxx Bytes Shared Memory" Even After SHARED_POOL Is Increased During Upgrade to 10gR2

Как быть?!

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вообще это может быть что угодно вплоть до дефекта в самом Oracle. Просто в качестве догадок:

- не выставлять параметр `DB_KEEP_CACHE_SIZE`
- увеличить `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET`
- уменьшить `SORT_AREA_SIZE`, `HASH_AREA_SIZE`